# How do I install IIS Express 7.5 onto Windows XP?

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-xp

While developing an ASP.NET application I tried to install IIS Express 7.5 onto Windows XP. I downloaded the installer and ran it - IIS installed okay (I see it in Add/Remove Programs list), but I didn't find anything for controlling it (like the IIS console).

My colleague told me I should use IIS Manager for IIS 6, I installed it, but it only allows me to control IIS 5 that was installed on XP from the very beginning. I tried to install IIS Manager for IIS 7 but when I ask it to connect to localhost it shown an error message saying it can't find `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly which AFAIK is only available on Vista and later versions.

How exactly do I install IIS Express 7.5 and some administration console to control it onto Windows XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIS 7.5 Express can be controlled via integration with VS2010 SP1, WebMatrix and the command line.

[From the IIS 7.5 readme](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1010/iis-75-express-readme/)

> You will most likely need an
>   Integrated Development Environment to
>   build web applications over IIS 7.5
>   Express. Microsoft WebMatrix provides
>   a simple and integrated user
>   experience for building both ASP.NET
>   and PHP websites using IIS 7.5
>   Express. You can use IIS 7.5 Express
>   with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta to
>   build and test web applications
>   instead of the built-in ASP.NET
>   Development Web Server (also known as
>   Cassini). It is also possible to run
>   IIS 7.5 Express using the command
>   line.

[I'd also check out the great blog post from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is no UI for IIS Express. You can install WebMatrix from following link which provides some basic IIS Express mangement functionality.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/

OR

You can also use IIS Express from command line. Below link provides info about how to start use IIS Express from command line.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/